# Where am I going wrong in this function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I am trying to write a function to query a database in mysql.  I want to calculate the age someone began working at a place of business.  I have their hire_date and birth_date rounded to 2 decimal places.  I have the query working but having trouble translating it into a function.

```
SELECT *,
ROUND(DATEDIFF(hire_date,birth_date)/365.25,1) AS AGE  
from Employees limit 15;
```

Works as a query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ah(hire_date date, birth_date date)
RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(hire_date,birth_date)/365.25,1) AS AGE
end
```

Returns error message: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(DATEDIFF(hire_date,birth_date)/365.25,1) AS AGE
end' at line 5

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: No RETURN. No semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to `RETURN` something. I think that you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ah(hire_date date, birth_date date)
RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN ROUND(DATEDIFF(hire_date,birth_date)/365.25,1);
```

Note that for this simple code with a single statement you do not need the `BEGIN/END` block.